# Make computed property update when Vuex's "router.currentRoute.name" changed

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vuex-modules

Consider wizard-type application; it has "proceed to next step" button, which text should be "next" until the last step of some interaction with user:

```html
<Button :text="!certainVuexStore.isLastStep ? 'next' : 'finish'" />
```

Each step, the view changes by Vue-router (the below code is TypeScript):

```js
export enum NamedRoutes {
  firstStep = 'FIRST_STEP',
  // ...
  lastStep = 'LAST_STEP'
}

export default new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      name: NamedRoutes.firstStep,
      path: '/',
      component: FirstStepView
    },
    // ...
    {
      name: NamedRoutes.lastStep,
      path: `/${NamedRoutes.lastStep}`,
      component: LastStepView
    }
  ]
});
```

So, the computed property `isLastStep` of vuex store could be declared as:

```js
import { VuexModule, Module, Action, getModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators';
import store, { StoreModuleNames } from './Store';
import router, { NamedRoutes } from '@Router/routes';


@Module({ name: StoreModuleNames.common, store, dynamic: true })
export default class Common extends VuexModule {

  public get isLastStep(): boolean {
    return router.currentRoute.name === NamedRoutes.lastStep;
  }

  @Action
  public proceedToNextStep(): void {
    switch (router.currentRoute.name) {
      // Two steps is enough for now
      case NamedRoutes.firstStep: {
        router.push(
            { name: NamedRoutes.lastStep },
            (): void => { console.log(router.currentRoute.name); })
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Currently, `isLastStep` will not be updated when `router.push({ name: NamedRoutes.lastStep }` will be executed. Because I ask this question, I don't know the cause exactly, but it may be:

1. Reactivity features of Vuex. It does not watch for the `router.currentRoute.name`.
2. `router.currentRoute.name` is external in respect to Vuex module.

What the exact cause and how I can solve this problem?